# Invariant Violation: "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be placed inside of the body of a function component."

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a function QRCodeReader which scans a QR code and displays the alert. I have a button named "Scan QR Code" and it has to call this QRCodeReader function which is in a different file. Button OnPress does not seem to work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    <CardItem>
        <Button rounded onPress={()=>{QRCodeReader()}}>
            <Text>
                Scan QR Code
            </Text>
        </Button>
    </CardItem>
```

Comment: This code looks good, but im sure there is more code involved.

Comment: Can you post the code of QRCodeReader as well ? It helps to identify the actual issue